# d3 networks, making un-connected nodes disappear based on threshold

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I had created a network with a slider, following the examples of @mbostock. The issue that I'm having is that I can't get rid of the nodes that are not longer connected. They keep appearing in my network.

The network is uploaded in: http://users.ox.ac.uk/~sedm4688/network.html

My slider codes is as follows:

```
//adjust threshold
$('#thersholdSlider').on('change', function () {
    var thresh = $(this).val();
    threshold(thresh);
})

function threshold(thresh) {
    console.log(thresh);
    links.splice(0, links.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < links_backup.length; i++) {
        if (parseFloat(links_backup[i].strength) > thresh) {
            links.push(links_backup[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(links.length);
    restart();
}
//Restart the visualisation after any node and link changes
function restart() {
    link = link.data(links);
    link.exit().remove();
    link = link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
        .attr('data-strength', function (d) {
            return d.strength
        })
        .attr('data-year', function (d) {
            return d.year
        })
        .attr('data-type', function (d) {
            return d.type
        })
        .attr('data-source-group', function (d) {
            return d.source.group
        })
        .attr('data-target-group', function (d) {
            return d.target.group
        })
        .attr('data-source', function (d) {
            return d.source.node
        })
        .attr('data-target', function (d) {
            return d.target.node
        })
        .attr("class", "link")
        .merge(link) //============= important =====================
        .on('mouseover', function () {
            link_tooltip.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", .9);
            link_tooltip.html(
                'Year: ' + $(this).attr('data-year') + '<br/> \
                Type: ' + $(this).attr('data-type') + '<br/> \
                Strength: ' + $(this).attr('data-strength') + '<br/>')
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
            $(this).addClass('active')
            var $el = $(this)
                console.log($el)
                $('.link').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                        var target_node = $(this).attr('data-target')
                            var source_node = $(this).attr('data-source')

                            if (!$('.node[data-node="' + source_node + '"]').hasClass('active'))
                                $('.node[data-node="' + source_node + '"]').addClass('active')
                                if (!$('.node[data-node="' + target_node + '"]').hasClass('active'))
                                    $('.node[data-node="' + target_node + '"]').addClass('active')
                    }
                })
        }).on('mouseout', function () {
            link_tooltip.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("opacity", 0);
            $(this).removeClass('active')
            $('.active').removeClass('active')
        });
}
//---End Insert---
var thresh = $('#thersholdSlider').val();
threshold(thresh);
});

$('#show-all-btn').click(function () {
    $('.node,.link').show()
})
```

Can anybody give me a hint or could help me to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your `restart` function you're binding the new data to the links only. Do the same for the nodes.

Comment: is there an example I can follow on how to do it? I'm learning D3, so I'm not that clear of what you mean @GerardoFurtado

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't that your code? Just do to the nodes the same thing you did to the links.